# Proper way to save/cache data generated by getserverSideProps in next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a Next.js app with a page which shows a listing of items. I have implemented getting item data from database during `getserverSideProps` which passes this data to the component to render. So far so good. The problem is that if the user clicks on the item, they navigate away to the item page, and then they click back and the data loading has to happen all over again. Somehow I'd want the initial data loading to happen on the server but then to be saved in a state on the client so that navigation between pages is quick. Is that possible?

I have figured out that I can pass data to the next page with `<Link href={{pathname: url, query:data}}>`. But is it possible to pass data back to the previous page? Or better yet, persist somewhere on the client?

Comment: Have you considered using `Cache-Control` headers as suggested in https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/ssr-caching?

Comment: I tried but it wasn't working for me. Namely, the data still had to be fully fetched.